# Interop.Excel set start position of app window on the screen

Tags: c#, ms-office

how can i set start position of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

This is example how can i succussfully modify size of this form.

```
var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.Height = height;
excelApp.Width = width;
```

But i cannot find anything about how to set start position of the form, for example set center align as default starting position of the form.

Does somebody have some idea?

Comment: I see Top and [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.left.aspx) on that interface. Try those.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I found it still useful to not run Excel maximized.  Beyond just needing the space, the ribbon put a pretty effective end to it.  Best not to mess with the user's preferences.

Comment: Rene: Thanks a lot, this helped me 100% according to my imagination!